# How to draw on canvas and make another object not draw on the same canvas while moving

Tags: javascript, css, animation, canvas

I have a blue circle which is rotating around the red circle and moves on canvas continuously in one direction as long as the button is pressed.

- Now I want to draw with the red circle while it is moving when the button is pressed (trace of its path).

Problems:

- when i try to draw on the canvas by not using `clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` the blue circle also starts to draw on the canvas while moving which I don't need.

Is it possible to draw with one circle and to not draw with another circle on same canvas?

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let positionX = 100;
let positionY = 100;
let X = 50;
let Y = 50;
let angle = 0;
let mouseButtonDown = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseButtonDown = true);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseButtonDown = false);

function circle(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
function direction(){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(positionX + X, positionY + Y, 10, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    positionX = 35 * Math.sin(angle);
    positionY = 35 * Math.cos(angle);
    ctx.fill();   
}
function animate(){
    if (mouseButtonDown) {
        X += positionX / 10;
        Y += positionY / 10;
    } else {
        angle += 0.1;
    }
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    circle();
    direction();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
}
animate();
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Canvas basics</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

We could introduce a new variable:
`let history = [{X,Y}]`
there we can keep the positions of the red circle as it moves, and we keep everything else in your code the same, we still use `clearRect` to clear and then redraw all elements.

On my sample code I'm pushing items to the history on `mouseup` that means that history won't show until the move is done, but you can play with that see if some other event has a better experience... same with what is drawn from history, I'm drawing a dashed line but it can be anything else.

Only thing I changed was the angle `angle += 0.05;` it was a bit fast for me.

My sample code below will draw something like this:
[image]

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
let positionX = 100
let positionY = 100
let X = canvas.width / 2;
let Y = canvas.height / 2;
let angle = 0;
let mouseButtonDown = false;
let history = [{ X, Y }]

document.addEventListener('mousedown', mousedown);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseup);

function mousedown() {
  mouseButtonDown = true
}

function mouseup() {
  mouseButtonDown = false
  history.push({ X, Y })
}

function drawHistory() {
  // draw the lines for history
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.setLineDash([5, 5]);
  ctx.moveTo(history[0].X, history[0].Y)
  for (let i = 1; i < history.length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(history[i].X, history[i].Y)
  }
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
  
  // draw line for current movement
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.setLineDash([10, 2]);
  ctx.moveTo(history[history.length-1].X, history[history.length-1].Y)
  ctx.lineTo(X, Y)
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function circle() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(X, Y, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
}

function direction() {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(positionX + X, positionY + Y, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  positionX = 35 * Math.sin(angle);
  positionY = 35 * Math.cos(angle);
  ctx.fill();
}

function animate() {
  if (mouseButtonDown) {
    X += positionX / 10;
    Y += positionY / 10;
  } else {
    angle += 0.05;
  }
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  circle();
  direction();
  drawHistory();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```