# How to control drawing on canvas using checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

[image]I am trying to control the drawing on canvas using a checkbox.

If the checkbox is checked the circle should write on the canvas, If the checkbox is unchecked the circle should not write on the canvas.

How can I extend this checkbox to an external source to control the writing and not writing on canvas( i.e. the output from an Arduino etc.)

```js
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
const ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');
canvas1.width = innerWidth;
canvas1.height = innerHeight;
const bgCan = copyCanvas(canvas1);
const redSize = 10, blueSize = 5; // circle sizes on pixels
const drawSpeed = 2; // when button down draw speed in pixels per frame
var X = 50, Y = 50;
var angle = 0;
var mouseButtonDown = false;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseButtonDown = true);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseButtonDown = false);
function copyCanvas(canvas) {
    const can = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {
        width: canvas.width, height: canvas.height
    });
    can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    return can;
}
function circle(ctx){
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, redSize, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill();
}
function direction(ctx){
    const d = blueSize + redSize + 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(d * Math.sin(angle) + X, d * Math.cos(angle) + Y, blueSize, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fill(); 
}
function animate(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width,  ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.drawImage(bgCan, 0, 0);
    if (mouseButtonDown) {
        circle(bgCan.ctx);
        X += Math.sin(angle) * drawSpeed;
        Y += Math.cos(angle) * drawSpeed;
    } else {
        angle += 0.1;
        circle(ctx);
    }
    direction(ctx);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);   
}
```

```css
#canvas1{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: There is no checkbox in your code ...

Comment: Your checkbox true/false condition doesn't really seem to change much, I'd have thought. You always want to draw the red circle and you always want to draw the blue circle. What the checkbox does is control whether or not you also want to draw a thick line between some set of points. Each mouse-interaction can add a new point. if the box is checked, you draw this thick path then each of the circles. (Assuming the blue should not be hidden by this thick path, but should instead appear in front of it) If the box isn't checked, don't worry about the thick line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

added one variable `checkBoxChecked` and it will hold the value of checkbox checked status. and in the `animate` function added one condition to draw the circle.

```
if(checkBoxChecked) { circle(bgCan.ctx) };
```

```js
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
const ctx = canvas1.getContext('2d');
canvas1.width = innerWidth;
canvas1.height = innerHeight;
const bgCan = copyCanvas(canvas1);
const redSize = 10,
  blueSize = 5; // circle sizes on pixels
const drawSpeed = 2; // when button down draw speed in pixels per frame
var X = 50,
  Y = 50;
var angle = 0;
var mouseButtonDown = false;
var checkBoxChecked = false;
document.getElementById("canvas1").addEventListener('mousedown', () => mouseButtonDown = true);
document.getElementById("canvas1").addEventListener('mouseup', () => mouseButtonDown = false);
function copyCanvas(canvas) {
  const can = Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), {
    width: canvas.width,
    height: canvas.height
  });
  can.ctx = can.getContext("2d");
  return can;
}

function circle(ctx) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(X, Y, redSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
}

function direction(ctx) {
 
    const d = blueSize + redSize + 5;
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(d * Math.sin(angle) + X, d * Math.cos(angle) + Y, blueSize, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
  
}

function animate() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.drawImage(bgCan, 0, 0);
  if (mouseButtonDown) {
    if(checkBoxChecked) { circle(bgCan.ctx) };
    X += Math.sin(angle) * drawSpeed;
    Y += Math.cos(angle) * drawSpeed;
  } else {
    angle += 0.1;
    circle(ctx);
  }
  direction(ctx);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function checkBoxClick() {
    checkBoxChecked = document.getElementById("chk").checked;
}
```

```css
#canvas1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chk" value="test" onclick="checkBoxClick();" />
<label for="chk"> Draw </label>
<canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the circle should not stop rotating and moving, It has to just stop drawing on the canvas. In your code snippet when it is unchecked the circle is not rotating and moving

Comment: sorry if I am not clear, but what I am asking is the checkbox should only control the drawing on the canvas, rest of the animation should be same. in your updated solution in the starting of code, when unchecked the total animation was not present. but it should only stop drawing on canvas rest of the things should be same(i.e the circle should move when mouse pressed but without drawing)

Comment: I was unable to move the circle using mousePress with updated code.

Comment: Now it is writing on the canvas when the Draw checkbox is unchecked!

Comment: @harsha you want to stop the circle too when the check box is unchecked?

Comment: No every thing should be same, The circle should not stop just the red circle should not draw on the canvas when unchecked. rest is same

Comment: I have updated the question with illustration please check if you have doubt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232842/discussion-between-deepu-reghunath-and-harsha).

Comment: I get a feeling this is a homework ... I've seen similar question before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67641635

@DeepuReghunath you have done 200% above and beyond pointing user on the right way, but this question was not clear or very specific, my guess the requirements will keep changing...

Comment: @HelderSepulveda okay